# How to get rid of double Parentheses of the equation number

Tags: equations, numbering, brackets

How to get rid of double Parentheses of the equation number, I appear like ((1)) , and I want it to be single like (1)

```
\usepackage{patches}    
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}    
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{tabstackengine}    
\usepackage{float}

\begin{equation}
Oh_d =\frac{\A_d}{\sqrt{\B_d\; R_d \; \C_d}},
\label{Eq_1}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I guess the culprit is the `patches` package, which is not on CTAN. Where did you get it?

Comment: Thank you, Bernard, I got it from the journal template. If I delete it, then all the images and some features disappeared.

Comment: What document class are you using?  Please identify the "journal template".  There's not enough information here to even make a reasonable guess.

Comment: You do not have to delete it, it probably can be patched.